# Repeat an Experiment and Store the Results in a Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a list. I can take a random sample from this list. I can apply a function to that sample. I can vary the size of the sample. I can store the result of each sample size in a new row. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

List = range(1,10)

def fun(Many_Things):
    Items = random. sample(List, Many_Things)
    return sum(Items)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Things' : range(1,5)})

df['Sample'] = df['Things'].apply(lambda x: fun(x))

print(df)
```

Which gives:

```
   Things  Sample
0       1       2
1       2      14
2       3      16
3       4      19
```

and when I run it again I get:

```
   Things  Sample
0       1       7
1       2      11
2       3      16
3       4      24
```

and when I run it again I get:

```
   Things  Sample
0       1       3
1       2      16
2       3      19
3       4      23
```

I would like to repeat this many times, each time storing the result in a new column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
import random
List = range(1,10)

def fun(Many_Things):
    Items = random. sample(List, Many_Things)
    return sum(Items)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Things' : range(1,5)})

for i in range(5):
    df['Sample'+str(i)]= df['Things'].apply(fun)

print(df)
```

---

```
   Things  Sample0  Sample1  Sample2  Sample3  Sample4
0       1        6        7        4        8        8
1       2       16       12        5       17       15
2       3       16       16       18       14       19
3       4       22       20       21       21       21
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `dict comprehension` and pass to [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) as a `**kwarg`:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

List = range(1,10)
def fun(Many_Things):
    Items = random. sample(List, Many_Things)
    return sum(Items)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Things' : range(1,5)})

d = {f"Sample{i+1}": df.Things.apply(lambda x: fun(x)) for i in range(5)}

df.assign(**d)
```

[out]

```
   Things  Sample1  Sample2  Sample3  Sample4  Sample5
0       1        2        9        8        4        4
1       2       12        8       13       15       12
2       3       17       20       20       16       13
3       4       19       26       23       20       16
```